# basic explanation http requests

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, httprequest

My question will probably be a simple one for most users on this forum, but I don't really understand it yet. The tutorials on this subject skip the absolute basics a bit to quick.

My question is: How are http requests made/called?
For example, a servlet has doPost, doDelete and doSave methods. I dont understand how and when these methods are called.

Can someone give a simple code example on how these methods are called (JSP web page to java servlet)? Especially the doSave and doDelete are interesting for me (with HtppRequest).

Thanks

Comment: have a look here http://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info

Comment: Thats a good example of post and get, but not delete or save. How do these two work?

Comment: There is no `doSave` in Servlet. PUT and DELETE requests can be sent by clients other than web browsers, like rich client applications, web service clients, or JavaScript functions sending AJAX requests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The request object is an instance of a javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest object. Each time a client requests a page the JSP engine creates a new object to represent that request.

The request object provides methods to get HTTP header information including form data, cookies, HTTP methods etc.